# how to open wxminiProgram in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

web/index.html

```
<!-- 引入外部js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://res.wx.qq.com/open/js/jweixin-1.3.2.js"></script>
```

how to use :`wx.miniProgram.navigateTo({url:''})` to open wxminiProgram?

Answer (score 0):

First, add script in web/index.html

```
<script defer src="https://res.wx.qq.com/open/js/jweixin-1.3.2.js"></script>
```

Second, use package js @JS('wx') allow script effective

```
dependencies:
  js: ^0.6.0

add file wx.dart：reference https://www.it1352.com/593448.html
import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS('wx') external WxClass get wx;
class WxClass {
  external MiniProgramClass get miniProgram;
}
```

Last, we can use wx.miniProgram.navigateTo({url:''}) to jump to weixin miniProgram , only in web-view page.